# VF Email Template With VF Component Not Working For Community Forgot password

Tags: community, controller, vf-email-template

I had changed Email template for "Forgot Password" as VF Email Template that contains a VF Component in Salesforce Community.
But when that VF Email Template -->VF Component have controller then email is not sent out.
If i remove controller from VF component then it works fine.

Is anyone else familiar with this issue?

[image: Email Template: Community Password Email]

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? Running into the same issue.

Comment: No still haven't found any solution on this.

Comment: Salesforce support acknowledges this bug. you can work around it by setting the recipient to the Contact for the community user and get info from that contact..

Comment: @RajendraRathore, Are you able to get the email if you set the recipientType as Contact. I also ran into the same issue, where i'm not able to get email even if i set the recipientType as Contact.

Answer (score 2):

I hope your issue has got resolved. If not yet, please refer the points mentioned below.

1. You will start receiving Forgot Password emails by setting recipient as **Contact** in Visualforce Email Template. There's no documentation related to this so far. But, this has worked for me when I was facing the similar issue.
2. If you still don't receive the emails, please check the security settings of the apex controller which you are using for Visualforce Component, if any. Give profile access to that apex class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajendra Rathore, it appears that the controller still doesn't work. the Contact workaround was because using the user as the recipient type was not populating merge fields. Hopefully they can sort that out someday.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we figure it out the root cause by logging a case to the salesforce,
The solution for this is, the apex controller which you are using in your vf component, **add that controller in the user's profile where the user is the username which you try to reset your password.**